# Getting angular configuration from docker once on developement environement and using the same image in production

Tags: angular, docker, continuous-integration

We are trying to use the same docker image (angular configuration set in docker.compose) in both environments development and production.

The objective is to use different configurations in different environments but in production , we are just pulling the dev image and deploying it in a container.

My question is as follow :

using the same image built in development environment , how to get environment variables from docker.compose when the image is deployed in production and my angular application starts?

Thank you.

Comment: Just visit this link which will create a configuration in the js file. hope it helps 
https://pumpingco.de/blog/environment-variables-angular-docker/